# Select columns across different databases

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do a select ( or insert) statement across different databases that are located on the same server? If yes, how?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You would specify the database by using the syntax `databasename.tablename`

Example:

```
SELECT 
    mydatabase1.tblUsers.UserID, 
    mydatabse2.tblUsers.UserID
FROM 
   mydatabase1.tblUsers
       INNER JOIN mydatabase2.tblUsers 
           ON mydatabase1.tblUsers.UserID = mydatabase2.tblUsers.UserID
```

Answer (score 10):

You can select from any other table with a [JOIN statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and using this type of syntax.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM db1.table1 A LEFT JOIN db2.table1 B ON A.id = B.id
```