# Copy added info from one mysql table to another in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in different mysql databases.

I would like to copy from table A to table B. Only one way.
I need to read last datetime from table B and then check if there any data added to table A after this readed datetime. If there is some data added, then copy it.

I tried this:

It writes one row if I refresh page, but I need it to write everything in one load!

```
do
   {

#TABLE A    
$querylastA = "SELECT * FROM `stock` ORDER BY `jrk` DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultlastA = mysql_query($querylastA) or die(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultlastA)){
$lastcodeA = $rows['datetime'];
}

#TABLE B
$querylastB = "SELECT * FROM `stockcopy` ORDER BY `jrk` DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultlastB = mysql_query($querylastB) or die(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultlastB)){
$lastcodeB = $rows['datetime'];
}

#TABLE A - NEXT DATE AFTER LAST DATE IN TABLE B
$querynextA = "SELECT datetime FROM stock WHERE datetime > '$lastcodeB' ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1";
$resultnextA = mysql_query($querynextA) or die(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultnextA)){
$nextcodeA = $rows['datetime'];
}


   mysql_query("INSERT INTO stockcopy(datetime, data1, data2) SELECT datetime, data1, data2 FROM stock WHERE datetime = '$nextcodeA'");
   echo "Date from table A " . $lastcodeA . "<br>";
   echo "Date from table B " . $lastcodeB . "<br>";
   }
 while ('$lastcodeA' == '$lastcodeB');
```

Comment: You can use a foreach loop to retrieve info from you first table to the second. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert data on a table using a `SELECT` statement, so all you need to do is put the condition in the `SELECT`.

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO table_example(foo, bar)
SELECT foo, bar FROM table_example2
WHERE time_condition > {SOME DATE}
```

This will insert into table_example the rows that the `SELECT` statement returns, which are the ones that satisfy the time condition. You will need to replace {SOME DATE} with an actual date (without brackets).

Also, please see: [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/mysql-insert-with-select)

And also: [Select columns across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases)

Comment: I need to read from one database and write to another, how I will manage DB connections? And also what happens if there are two inputs after my datetime?

Comment: INSERT INTO db2.table_example(foo, bar)
SELECT foo, bar FROM db1.table_example2
WHERE time_condition > {SOME DATE}

Comment: @Jal_, are you doing this with PHP, or directly in a MySQL console? Also, what do you mean by "two inputs after my datetime"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with little to no knowledge of SQL, but with a bit of creativity :)

Create a temporary table (`table_c`), and copy the contents of `table_a` there.

Then manually (this means by running delete queries in phpmyadmim) delete the information that doesn't matter anymore ( `DELETE FROM table_c WHERE id < 1000` for example ).

Then, export the info from `table_c` and import it into `table_b` (and delete `table_c`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in: `while ('$lastcodeA' == '$lastcodeB');`

Changed it to: `while ($lastcodeA != $lastcodeB);` now it works! Thank you all :)