# How to update a database (d2) based on the information of another database (d1)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

i managed to install xampp with wordpress on localhost. In a subfolder of wordpress i installed a php program. Everything works well, but i have a problem, i want my wordpress members to be able to login and use my php program (a web app). The problem is that's i'm just started to learn php a few weeks ago, so i can't really do it, i don't have money to spend on a developer, so this site is my only help.

I found an easier way for me to do essentially the same, but i have some problems implementing it: i want to link database1 (wordpress database) with database2 (php app database). Essentially i want to update database2 informations based on information on database1, i.e. if someone update his password on wordpress for example i want his password also to be updated on database2, if i delete or add an user on wordpress i want them also to be deleted or added on database2 from my web app.

The informations on the two database are:

database1
table1
user_id
email
password

database2
table2
ID
email 
password
name
last name

How can i do this with php & mysql? I really have some difficulties implementing it. Can someone help or at least give me some indication on how to implement it. I'm a newbie.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases
use database.table to specify both database and table

Comment: Thank you Lectem, i did not stumble upon this question during my research. Thank you very much again!