# how to select records from multiple database in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I want to use multiple database because I have 1 database which contain 40 tables and it doesnt seem good.Thats why I want to create another database but problem is I am not able to join this databases at one query for example
I have 'core' database and it contains users table which has user_id column
second database is post database and I need get user_id from users table which is in 'core' database like below

```
SELECT post_message from posts where 'core'.user_id=123
```

is that possible?or should I stick with one database?I have also foreign key problem which is related with database relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is **SQL SERVER** Product, You can call the Object residing on another DB like below

```
SELECT * FROM [DB_NAME].[Schema_Name].[Table_NAME]
```

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Employee
```

**For MySQL :** Please go through the below ans
[Select columns across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases)

Comment: it is mysql,so how can I do this?

Comment: Give it a try. I dont know exact synax in Mysql

Comment: Also I use PDO to connect db

Comment: okay but I firstly connect with database via pdo then I use select

Comment: I have tested as you said at comment and it worked! Great! Thank you