# Is it possible to fetch data from five databases in just one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a program that output results from database but the source of data comes from five databases. Is it possible to output the data coming from five databases? Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to get data from multiple databases using single query

Comment: Even if I use the commands like "JOIN", "UNION" and other commands like that? @Anil

Comment: Do you mean databases or tables?

Comment: Does all those schemas in the same database or different database ?

Comment: It's database. I'm using MySQL and PHP for my program. All databases are stored in my local server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select columns across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases)

Comment: Yes it is possible if all database are on single MSSQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible.
Try like below query:

**

```
select  DD.DISTRICT_NAME, MM.MANDAL_NAME,GP_NAME from 
(
select  District_id,substring(sn_vo_id,3,4) as mandal,Gp_id,sn_vo_id,MEMBER_ID,sn_member_name,sn_amount_paid_date,Project_Type_ID,Activity,status
from pop_nov18..tbl_scsp_hlp_new where   hh_id is  null and MEMBER_ID not in
 (select MEMBER_ID from pop_nov18..IB_SHG_MEMBER_DETAILS)  
) a left join UnnathiMasters.[dbo].[vo_master] vo on a.sn_vo_id=vo.VO_id
left join UnnathiMasters.[dbo].[gp_master] GP on a.Gp_id=GP.GP_ID
left join UnnathiMasters.[dbo].[mandal_master] MM on a.mandal=mm.MANDAL_ID
left join UnnathiMasters.[dbo].[district_master] DD on a.District_id=DD.DISTRICT_ID
left join SC_ST_Bluefrog_2013..SCSP_HLP_MASTER AC on a.Activity=AC.sub_activity_code
```

**

In above query,POP_nov18,UnnathiMasters and SC_ST_Bluefrog_2013 are three different databases.

Answer (score 0):

sample select  query for getting data from multiple database

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.MyTable
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: What is the "dbo" parameter?