# Stored procedure to get table data from different database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Can we get table data from multiple database using stored procedure?

Comment: Can we get data?

Comment: If on the same server then duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases - if across servers, then I believe the feature request remains outstanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select columns across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674115/select-columns-across-different-databases)

Comment: As above we can get data from two tables, but if we need to get table data more than two databases, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to access table using database name.
e.g. 
Select * From myDb1.Table1
Select * From myDb2.Table2

Make sure you have access to both the database or both the databases are linked if they are on different servers